# How do you create a dynamic canvas from an image in Haskell's Reflex lib?

Tags: javascript, html, haskell, canvas, reflex

I am representing an image as:

```
data Image = Image { size :: V2 Int, buffer :: UVector.Vector Word32 }
```

That is, a row-major unboxed array of RGBA Word32 pixels. That format is the same used by JavaScript's Canvas's ImageData. You could blit such a vector into a JS's canvas with something like:

```
function blit(canvas, img){
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.putImageData(new ImageData(img.buffer, img.size.x, img.size.y), 0, 0);
};
```

What I want is to have a widget on Haskell that calls this "blit" function on the cames every other frame using a `Dynamic Image`. How is that possible?